# GeoServer init script not working

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu

I have configured the latest version of GeoServer on a AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo su
apt-get update -y
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -y
apt-get install unzip -y

cd /usr/share
mkdir geoserver
cd geoserver

wget https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/main/geoserver-main-latest-bin.zip
unzip geoserver-main-latest-bin.zip

echo "export GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver" >> ~/.profile
. ~/.profile

useradd -m -U geoserver
sudo chown -R geoserver /usr/share/geoserver/
```

By running the commands above, I can then execute `sh bin/startup.sh`, and GeoServer will run successfully.

According to my reading, it sounds like, instead, we're supposed to run GeoServer using a service.

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/linuxscript.html), I copied the [Linux init](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/5c56ec58bc153d3a7dd6ef198f9eeaf7/geoserver_deb) script into this file, and made it executable.

```
nano /etc/init.d/geoserver
chmod +x /etc/init.d/geoserver
```

I then changed the default values

```
nano /etc/default/geoserver
```

```
USER=geoserver
GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
GEOSERVER_HOME=/usr/share/geoserver
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

Finally, I start the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start geoserver
```

The service seems to start correctly. It's status is given as **active**.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~$ sudo systemctl status geoserver
● geoserver.service - LSB: GeoServer OGC server 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/geoserver; generated) 
Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-01-07 20:45:45 UTC; 15s ago 
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   
Process: 7244 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/geoserver start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 23 (limit: 1143)        
Memory: 271.3M     
CPU: 14.484s  
CGroup: /system.slice/geoserver.service     
└─7251 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx512m
DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/geoser> 
Jan 07 20:45:45 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: GeoServer OGC server...  
Jan 07 20:45:45 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx geoserver[7244]:  * Starting GeoServer daemon geoserver
Jan 07 20:45:45 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx geoserver[7244]:    ...done.   
Jan 07 20:45:45 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Started LSB: GeoServer OGC server.
```

However, I get the following error if I try and access GeoServer through the browser:

```
HTTP ERROR 503 Service Unavailable
URI:    /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage
STATUS: 503
MESSAGE:    Service Unavailable
SERVLET:    -
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.48.v20220622
```

Is this the correct way to run GeoServer in a production environment, i.e.: without using `startup.sh` directly? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One question per Question, please. Bulleted question lists are a quick path to Question closure.

Comment: @Vince Removed second question

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: In general best practice is to use a servlet container like tomcat to run the war file rather than use the platform independent binary which needs a lot of changes to run in production.